# Is there a way make a sprite have a permanent color?

Tags: javascript

In play.js, you can make a sprite by this:

```
var derp
Function setup () {
derp = createSprite(width / 2, height / 2, 600, 400);
Function draw () {
drawSprites();
}
```

This makes a big sprite, but it changes colors every time the program runs. How do make it on one color always when it runs?

Comment: First, JS is case sensitive, `Function` and `function` are two very different things in JS. Second, what kind of sprites? JS itself doesn't have a `createSprite` or `drawSprites` function. Do you use some framework?

Comment: Yeah is was a play.js thing on hack club so idk